# How to create a Custom AuthorizeAttribute that redirects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` that

1. checks for user login.

   1. if logged: redirect to place1.
   2. else: redirect to place2.
2. checks for user activation.

   1. if logged && not activated: redirect to place3

No clue how to do. I mean, how can I access the user info inside the attribute in order to check it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // the user is authenticated => redirect to place1
            // you could get the current user from the 
            // filterContext.HttpContext.User property and query your provider
            // to verify if he is activated (whatever that means in your specific context)

            var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                contoller = "foo",
                action = "bar",
            });
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeValues);
        }
        else
        {
            // the user is not authenticated => redirect to place2
            var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                contoller = "bazingaS",
                action = "theBaz",
            });
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeValues);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to check if the user is active. Like `if (!user.active) ...` how to treat that? ("active" is a property in my model).

Comment: Put the other checks in the `if` clause too.

Comment: Yes, but i dont know how to access it there. Thats the real problem.

Comment: There's no such notion as *user being active* in ASP.NET MVC. That's something that only exists in your specific context and set of frameworks you are using. As I already explained in my answer you could get the currently authenticated username using the `filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` property. Once you get that value you could query your underlying data providers or membership services or whatever you are using to decide whether this user is active or not (whatever that means in your context).

Comment: Yeah, you definitely made a wrong question. Good luck with the next one.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - Does the above implementation requires `FormAuthentication` implemenentation to be in done while login ?